# How can i loop through an array using innerHTML

Tags: foreach, equals, innerhtml, operator-keyword

```html
    <div id="demo"></div><br>
    <script>
        let a = [1,2,3];
        a.forEach(function(item){
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=item;
        })
    </script>
```

From the above code I can only get last digit. Why it is not showing all digits in the array. But When i use `innerHTML+=item` it is working fine. What is the difference between = and += here. I found that every tutorial explaining that += means x = x + y. But I believe there is a huge logic behind the scenes of += But no any one is expaining about this. It will be very helpfull anyone can explain this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you write "=" it's mean that you *clear* the text and put new text in `innerHTML`, when you write "+=" it's mean that you *add* text to whatever in `innerHTML`.

Comment: Hi Zvi, Thank You Very Much for your Wonderfull and simple explanation on this complicated logic. Now i understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

= and += are not the same

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=item;
```

will set to a single item each time in the loop. So going through three times your would be setting the innerHTML like this:

- `innerHTML = '1'`
- `innerHTML = '2'`
- `innerHTML = '3'`

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML+=item;

will append the item and is the same as

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML + item;
```

So each time through you will be executing:

- `innerHTML = originalHTML + '1'`
- `innerHTML = originalHTML + '1' + '2'`
- `innerHTML = originalHTML + '1' + '2' + '3'`

Comment: Hi Derek, You have given a superb explanation. Thank you very much. I also eager to know why I getting only the last digit (3) when i use only = operator.

Comment: If this answer your question it is helpful and kind to accept the answer so the question is marked resolved.

Comment: Derek S, sorry for delay to accept your answer. I was bit busy with some urgent works. Thank You So Much for clear and detail explanation with logic.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between = and += here?

= You are assigning the value to something.
+= You are not only assigning but also holding the previous value and also assigning and concatenating the previous value with current value.

Comment: Hi spgk, Thank You very much for giving me another insights on the logic. Also what is the reason behind i getting only 3 when i use only = operator.